# Why did UIKit or Cocoa have to be coded in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit

An ambiguous statement is periodically made that objective-c was necessary for the creation of UIKit & its predecessor Cocoa, however it is rarely clarified or elaborate upon. Something vaguely to do with message forwarding. But all user interfaces forward events, regardless of what language they are written in. So I ask now: what specific aspects of Objective-C were crucial for the implementation of either UIKit or its predecessor Cocoa, which C++ or Java could not have also provided?

Answer (score 1):

The aspect is the ability to bind late and type dynamically.

There are several examples for the need, but the clearest is the responder chain. Try to write it in Swift (without the usage of Objective-C or the RTE of Objective-C.) Go ahead!

And no, not every language. I. e. in C++ they had to add signals and slots to make the language useful for modern UI programming. Basically every language with no dynamic binding – at least as fall back – is not useful for that.

- Swift uses Objective-C as dynamic door opener.
- C++ uses signals and slots.
- C# has delegates.

BTW: The concept of GUI and the concept of dynamic dispatching was invented at the same place at the same time. Maybe there is a reason for that.

Comment: OK and why can't the responder chain be done in either Java or C? Can you elaborate on what is so special about the responder chain?

Comment: Suppose you want to find the first responder that can handle some message, say `foo:`. In Objective-C, you can say, "does the first responder support `foo:`? No? Okay, does the next responder support `foo:`? No? Okay, does the next responder support `foo:`? Oh, it does? Great! Invoke `foo:` on that object." And that's why things just work when you wire them up to First Responder in Interface Builder. This is much less simple to do without dynamic dispatch mechanisms in place.

Comment: Ur kidding right? Ever hear of a stack? Push the first responder onto a stack, then pop it offer in resignFirstResponder.

Comment: Nobody is kidding. The problem is, that the items in the responder chain do not necessarily inherit from the same base class and that the sent message can be customized. Of course you can write that in C and of course you can write a simulator in another language. But the point is, that you *have to* do this.

Comment: Did Java and C++ exist when NeXTSTEP (the predecessor of Cocoa) was created?

Comment: Java: No, C++: Yes

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Can u give an example of a message that won't be dealt with the same down the responder chain?

Comment: @Sun `myCustomMessage` Some of the subclasses in the responder chain implements a method for it. Other do not. However, the framework "scanning" the responder chain have never heard of it.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I think I'd find this easier to get if I saw a concrete example. If there are 30 event types using 20 different event records, e.g. touchedDownInside which provides an x,y value, why is it expressly necessary to have dynamic typing? If these were something else e.g. network packets, it would be a simple matter of ignoring them and passing them on. Not so for GUIs?

Comment: @Sun I'm not talking about events, that are typically system created and therefore limited and well-known to the system. I talk about the action messages. There is an example for such a message in my last posting: `myCustomMessage`. If you want to have more examples go through the menus of every app on your system. Or read an introduction to C++, signals and slots. Then you will see the need for it.

Comment: Or try to implement a modeless info panel interacting with windows or completely different itms shown. Or think of an export function, possibly related to a selection in a text field, the content of a whole window or even a document shown in different windows. Just try to implement it without dynamic techniques. As I said: Go ahead and try it.